# Guessing data from statistics

Tags: sampling, descriptive-statistics

If I have a number of statistics/information of a data set, e.g. mean, SD, skew, kurtosis, % data values within a certain range, etc, how might I go about trying to deduce a portion of the actual data. In my case, the data are not numbers, but rather subjects in a study, and therefore have more information (and thus associated constraints).

I just don't know where to begin with this problem. Is there some branch of statistics that might be relevant to look into? Some have pointed me to sampling, but this seems quite general. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you're asking about *[imputation](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/imputation)* of missing data. You might like to start [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imputation_%28statistics%29), and maybe take a look at [this](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/arm/missing.pdf). Many stats packages have a variety of methods available for such things. Those also give you some handy additional search terms.